# Flows Disappeared from Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I've been using Dataprep for months, and have a lot of different flows built in one of my projects.  I was working with it this morning, but now when I log in, the project in Dataprep is blank, like I'm a brand new user.  I'm starting to panic because months of work has vanished!  Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do?

Things I've tried without success:

- I switched into a different project and I can see that project's
  flows listed.
- Logged out/in
- restarted browser

Comment: Have you disabled and reenabled Dataprep or the Dataflow API? This would result in all the Dataprep metadata being [deleted](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/resources/enable-disable#effect_of_disabling_dataprep_name_short). If it disappeared without you making any changes to your APIs, please open a [Dataprep issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491499) reporting this with your project number included in the description.

Comment: +1 I suspect the Dataflow or Dataprep API was disabled at some point; this clears all user data in Dataprep.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, you are correct.  It turns out we received an email from google with the subject "[Action Required] Please migrate off JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch Endpoints" (specifically storage@v1).  We were not using this API with the solutions we developed within this project, so one of our developers deactivated it.  It showed the affected dependencies, which included the Dataflow API.  DataPrep was not disabled, nor did it need to be reenabled before accessing it again...it just lost it's metadata like both Ali T and James commented.

Google Cloud Support recommends exporting the recipes and flows (manually I believe) as the best way to prevent DataPrep working file loss in the future.